# Invalid file coverage object, missing keys, found:data

Tags: cypress

coverage-final.json has an unnecessary data property for some files, which is breaking merge.

{"C:\Code\app\src\App.js": {"data":{"path":"C:\Code\app\src\App.js","statementMap": {}},
,"C:\Code\app\src\index.js": {"data":{"path":"C:\Code\app\src\index.js","statementMap"{},
,"C:\Code\app\src\components\logo\Logo.tsx": {"path":"C:\Code\app\src\components\logo\Logo.tsx","statementMap":{}},

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing App.js and changing index.js to index.tsx